# Which version of MySQL 5.5 is preferable for performance based?

Tags: mysql

We are planned to use MySQL 5.5 but we do saw that there are many sub-versions available in mysql5.5 as follows (mysql5.5.1; mysql5.5.3; mysql5.5.6; mysql5.5.8; mysql5.5.9) among these which one would be preferable for performance and scalability version.I need you help please...

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a client with 3 Machines. Each server has the following

```
MySQL 5.5.9
192GB RAM
162GB InnoDB Buffer Pool
Dual HexaCore (That's Right, 12 CPUs)
Circular Replication
```

With these settings

```
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_io_capacity=65536
```

and Semisynchronous Replication Enabled

I have all 12 CPUs engaged
InnoDB works like a dream
Performance is what I got !!!

By all means, GO GET THE LATEST, MySQL 5.5.11

Comment: Hi @user626206 I have two clients with MySQL 5.5.11 right now. It was announced in Twitter on April 8th as production release.

Answer (score 0):

In typical circumstances a version 5.5.B is preferable to 5.5.A if B>A because often a version B is floated so as to bridge the deficiencies of A. Still, situations may defer, you have to read documentation, at least, the part that tells you how a version B differs from predecessor A to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Every sub-version contains a fix for either performance or security issues.
Therefore you'll allways want to get the latest version, especially for a production environment when you're open to the internet.

The performance difference between 5.5 and 5.5.9 isn't noticable, and in general all mysql versions scale well and have good performance.

But with 5.5 you might run into security issues where as 5.5.9 won't

And btw, the latest is 5.5.11 so you should get that

Comment: Hi @s4uadmin Its really a precious information you have provided Thanks for your  help..

Comment: @zerkms "Every sub-version contains a fix for either performance or security issues."

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest [Percona mysql server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/)